# How to implement a Left Shifter using Right Shifter?

Tags: vhdl, bit-shift, logical-operators, bluespec

I have implemented a Right Shifter(32 bits) using 5 stages of multiplexers (Shift1/2/4/8/16). my question is how can I extend my implementation to implement the Left Shifter with minimum additional hardware ?

Comment: this seems like a hardware question.

Comment: @IsThatSo  VHDL is a hardware description language. You infer hardware in it. Notice Morten's answer involves two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Shift left can be done using shift right by reversing the argument vector, shift right, and then reverse the result, thus:

```
shift_left(arg, n) = reverse(shift_right(reverse(arg), n))
```

Function for reverse of `std_logic_vector` can be found in [reverse_any_vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13584918/2352082).